# Abnormally low participation on Facebook posts, is something wrong?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I help manage the Facebook page of a business with 10,000+ very dedicated fans.

While there's highs and lows, the page normally receives fairly strong feedback on any type of post. The most reliable guarantor for strong participation is product sweepstakes. The products are relatively pricey and fans appreciate the opportunity to get some of them for free.

We have a series of videos that come with a sweepstakes. Yesterday, I posted an image announcing the video and the sweepstakes.

The participation was obscenely low - so much so that I can't help but suspect something is wrong: after 6 hours and purportedly **over 4,000 views**, we gained **three likes**, and **one entry** in the sweepstakes (in the form of a comment underneath the post).

For comparison, the previous sweepstakes, after 24,000 views, yielded 196 likes, 213 comments, and 104 shares.

The sweepstakes are almost identical in layout and prizes on offer.

I restarted the whole thing this morning, this time embedding the video itself, and boosting the post to our audience and their friends, but the numbers are not looking much better.

What could be wrong?

Could we be being blocked or throttled by Facebook for some reason?

How would one go about investigating that?

Comment: I've cross-posted this in the Facebook business support community [here](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10210847754850100&added&rdrhc)... if something useful comes up there, I'll post it here.

Comment: I know that Facebook regularly adjusts what gets shown in people's timelines, but if you've got regularly fans as you say that seems a bit off, even for 4k views. I don't have any particular insights, though.